# Special ending in Eversion

Tags: eversion

How do I get the special ending in the Steam version of Eversion? I looked all over the last level, but I can't find a way to trigger it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right before the end of level seven there is an enemy, two shrubs, and floating segments that are too high to jump to normally.

There is a dimensional layer that turns all of the wandering enemies into unmoving hazards. Use that dimension to put the enemy into position to jump on him, then get to the goal and finish the level while still in that layer.

*Note*: It appears that some people have not gotten the achievement along with the special ending.

[Related image](http://img717.imageshack.us/img717/5508/thingv.jpg)

[Original source](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1298849)

Comment: It worked, but it took me some time to find the layer at the beginning of the level.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone finds it useful, once you are in the right dimension (where blocks are grey, everything else is beige, and the enemies don't move), cross the checkpoint in the middle of the level and kill yourself. You will appear at the checkpoint. Now, go back to the start, at the upper left side, where there's the portal to a dimension where enemies move. Activate the dimension and wait exactly 17 seconds, then change the dimension again. Walk to the end of the level; the enemy at the last jump will have moved to the exact spot for you to jump on him and get to the end of the level in the beige dimension, activating the alternative ending. Hope it helps!

Comment: Do you have some source to provide?